# Cambiar la configuración de locale en toda la app

Tags: android

Con el siguiente código se cambia el idioma de la `activity`

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("es_ES");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

El problema es que si esta `activity` lanza una nueva no se mantiene la configuración en la nueva. Debo de repetir el código en todas las Activitys.

¿Como se podría mantener la configuración durante toda la app?

Comment: Mírate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself (en)

Comment: prueba con el código de mi respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buena pregunta, en realidad no existe una propiedad
para definir o mantener globalmente el locale en la aplicación.

Puedes repetir el código en la aplicación, lo cual no sería correcto, pero mi opción sería crear una clase Activity base la cual contendría el código para cambiar el locale, de la cual extiendan tus actividades o crear una clase que extienda de Application donde definas configuración de tu locale.

algo similar a esta implementación:
http://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/

tiene una clase para configurar locale la cual se define en la clase que extiende Application y con esto aplica para toda la aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Yo para que se aplique en todas las `actividades`, uso `MyAplication.java` que extiende de Aplication

```
import android.app.Application;


public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Locale locale = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Locale locale = new Locale("es_ES");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Locale locale = new Locale("es_ES");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

    }

}
```

Y en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml que la aplicación se extiende de `MyAplication.java`

```
<application
    android:name="tu.package.name.MyApplication"
```

**Update**
Si rotas el dispositivo debes forzar la carga del idioma en `onConfigurationChanged` para que así se establezca.

Comment: Mi código para aplicar el idioma no debería de ir en el método onCreate?

Comment: @aldakur revisando mi código, si veo que lo lógico seria en onCreate, haré pruebas tambien de cómo es la manera lógica para solventar eso

Comment: @aldakur has encontrado ya la solución? he actualizado la respuesta

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Webserviceis pero al final utilice la otra respuesta. Tú respuesta también me funcionó por eso le di un +1 pero la otra respuesta es realmente escalable para otra app.

Comment: @aldakur ok, también comprueba que si usas fragments se cargue bien el locale, porque yo en una de mis apps tuve problemas, entre rotar el dispositivo usando fragments y los de settings...